# Why the \pounds has different result in article and ctexart?

Tags: xetex

In ctexart, code as follow:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\begin{document}
    \verb|$\pounds$->|$\pounds$,\medspace \verb|\pounds->|\pounds
\end{document}
```

the result as follow:
[image]
In article, code as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \verb|$\pounds$->|$\pounds$,\medspace \verb|\pounds->|\pounds
\end{document}
```

the result as follow:
[image]
So can you help me to solve the question?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: in xetex you may as well just have `\def\pounds{£}` I think, all the `\pounds` weirdness in core latex is for classic 8bit OT1 computer modern

Comment: If I compile with `pdflatex` I get the expected output.

Answer (score 6):

`\pounds` has a complicated internal definition to cope with the original OT1 encoding of computer modern but it doesn't really make any sense in xetex or luatex if using Unicode fonts. We should probably adjust fontspec so things work by default but simply defining `\pounds` to be £ is safe enough:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\def\pounds{£}
\begin{document}
    \verb|$\pounds$->|$\pounds$,\medspace \verb|\pounds->|\pounds
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get a version following math alphabet commands you can do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\def\pounds{£}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\sbox0{$\mathit{x\xdef\mathitfam{\the\fam}}$}% set up mathit
\Umathcode `\£ 7 \mathitfam `\£
}

\showoutput
\begin{document}
    \verb|$\pounds$->|$\pounds$,\medspace \verb|\pounds->|\pounds

$a£\pounds + \mathsf{b£\pounds} + \mathbf{c£\pounds} + \mathit{d£\pounds}$
\end{document}
```

Where the difficulty is you need to pull the default from mathit font as the normal math italic does not have the right character.

Comment: in the classical setup the math pound is italic not upright.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well yes but the upright £ in cmr10 is a $ so classical setup isn't a great example (but arguably the mathcode should be 7 so it follows the current math fam, but I'd say that was an issue with £ \pounds and £ ought to be the same I think.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer _£_ added for you

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but what I need is `\pounds` in Mathematical model is different in `article` and `ctexart`. I can't understand why this happening.

Comment: @jiawei this makes \pounds work as well as £  the problem is that ctexart loads fontspec which makes the mathrm font be the Unicode text font instead of the legacy OT1 encoded font that is generally a good thing but the definition of \pounds is not expecting that so it selects $ as OT1 fonts use the same number for $ and £ with italic fonts showing a pound sign and upright fonts showing $

Comment: What is upright fonts, `\textup`? But I can't get the `$` by using `\textup{\pounds}`, just `£`

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.

Comment: You means that `fontspec` package effects the output, and I use `article+fontspec`+`xelatex` output `$` successfully by `\pounds` in math mode, and the font of `$` is the same as main font. So `\pounds` in math mode is actually print as a text mode symbol in math mode?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, and I have said I used `article` and `fontspec`, maybe you saw wrongly:)

Answer (score 2):

The code produces the expected output if run with `pdflatex`.

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, it happens that `ctexart` defines `\textfont5` (or whatever family is assigned to `\mathit`) to be Latin Modern Italic in TU encoding, whereas it stays Computer Modern Italic in OT1 encoding with `article`.

Since `\pounds` is defined to be `\mathsterling` when found in math mode and `\mathsterling` does

```
\mathit{\mathchar"7024}
```

you get a dollar symbol with `ctexart`.

You can fix the issue with the following workaround that should work with all engines.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\mathit{\Umathchar"7 "0 "A3}}
\fi

\begin{document}

\verb|$\pounds$->|$\pounds$,\medspace \verb|\pounds->|\pounds

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it might make sense to modify `\mathsterling`, if you always use (Xe|Lua)LaTeX to respect the current math family (and produce an upright sterling symbol by default):

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \Umathchardef\mathsterling="7 "0 "A3
\fi

\begin{document}

\verb|$\pounds$->|$\pounds$,\medspace \verb|\pounds->|\pounds

$\pounds\mathit{\pounds}\mathbf{\pounds}\mathsf{\pounds}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want italic by default, you can do

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\mathsterling}{}{%
    \ifnum\fam<0
      \mathit{\mathsterlingchar}
    \else
      \mathsterlingchar
    \fi
  }
  \Umathchardef\mathsterlingchar="7 "0 "A3
\fi

\begin{document}

\verb|$\pounds$->|$\pounds$,\medspace \verb|\pounds->|\pounds

$\pounds\mathit{\pounds}\mathbf{\pounds}\mathsf{\pounds}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \mathbf{£}  ? (see my answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The standard definition is meant not to make `\pounds` to change according to the math family. It's a “feature”, I'd say.

Comment: I know but I suspect that is an artefact of the difficulty in getting £ at all using OT1, £ isn't used as a fixed math symbol if it's used in math at all it ought to follow the digits as far as font choice goes (I'd have made it default to upright as well).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a simpler approach to the problem.

Comment: naturally:-)... It's simpler but it doesn't make £ and \pounds produce the same output, which is what my version was aiming to get

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\newunicodecharacter{£}{\pounds}`